# Angular JS -- Applying ng-repeat to things added to the DOM asyncronously

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, dom

I am working on a "widget" library which creates a dashboard with draggable, dynamically loaded widgets.  The overall solution is using Angular.  Each widget has both a JavaScript file and a Jade file.  For some of our widgets, the result uses angular directives like ng-repeat.  Here is the code that one particular widget is generating:

```
<tr ng-repeat="account in vmAccountList">
    <td ng-click="showTransactions(account)">{{account.account.accountNumber}}</td>
    <td ng-click="showTransactions(account)">{{account.account.accountDisplayName.defaultNormalAccountName}}</td>
    <td ng-click="showTransactions(account)" ng-if="account.account.acctTypeId==1">{{account.account.runningBalance.amount | currency}}</td>
    <td ng-click="showTransactions(account)" ng-if="account.account.acctTypeId==3">{{account.account.currentBalance.amount | currency}}</td>
    <td ng-click="showTransactions(account)" ng-if="account.account.acctTypeId==4">{{account.account.currentBalance.amount | currency}}</td>
    <td><a ng-click="deleteAccount(account.itemId);" class="btn btn-default btn xs">X</a></td>
</tr>
```

The problem is have is the ng-repeat is never getting processed -- the resulting widget just renders a single row with all the merge tags above in place, completely unaware of the data.  I have tried many different combinations of $scope.$apply and $scope.$digest -- none of them work.  I'm gathering that the problem is because by the time my widget gets downloaded, the JADE rendered and the JS applied it is probably too "late" in the page's lifecycle to have Angular process directives.

Is there a command to manually tell Angular to go find all the ng-repeats and render them?  Failing that, is there a way to insert things into the DOM that are loaded aync and have Angular apply these commands?

The code that is loading the widget and populating the DOM:

```
$.get('/v1/widget/' + name, (data) => {
    var jadeCode = data;
    $.get('/v1/widget/js/' + name, (data) => {
        if(!w)
            w = 2;
        if(!h)
            h = 1;
        if(that._lastX + w > SDB.NumberOfVerticalLanes) {
            that._lastX = 0;
            that._lastY += h;
        }

        var retVal = new Widget(name, domId, that._lastX, that._lastY, w, h, '');   
        var processedWidget = eval(data + "(retVal)");
        processedWidget._jadeFN = jade.compile(jadeCode);

        var content = processedWidget._jadeFN(processedWidget.JadeScope);
        //The 'content variable contains the markup I posted above at this point, and SetContent applies it to the DOM
        processedWidget.SetContent(content);
    });
});
```

The SetContent method highlighted by comment in the above snippet is simply using jquery to insert the new content:

```
this.SetContent = (cnt) => {
    this.Content = cnt;
    $("#" + this.Id).html(cnt);
};
```

I apologize if some of my terminology (specifically about Angular) is not correct, I'm only somewhat familiar with it, and frankly I am not a big fan.  But the project uses it and so I have to find a way to get this working.  Thanks!

Comment: From my understanding when you have a ng-repeat it sets a watcher on the array value in your case "vmAccountList" so when you change it it should update. If for some odd reason it does not you can try $apply after it gets the data.

Comment: I have tried both -- it appears that Angular is not aware of my ng-repeat at all, and even if I update vmAccountList or call $apply it does not update my component at all.  We know the code works if it's not loaded asyncronously -- but as soon as we load it and add it to the DOM dynamically the ng-repeat stops working.

Comment: Try adding $scope.$apply() right after the processedWidget.SetContent line. If that doesn't work, then I am guessing your html replace is removing the angular links in that process. Would need the full page code to dig deeper.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution ended up being using Angular's $compile to create a data-aware DOM node, as shown below:

```
//Step 1:  Create empty widget
var retVal = new Widget(name, domId, that._lastX, that._lastY, w, h, '');   
//Step 2:  Process Widget Javascript
var processedWidget = eval(data + "(retVal)");
//Step 3:  Process the Jade and set the content
processedWidget._jadeFN = jade.compile(jadeCode);
var content = processedWidget._jadeFN(processedWidget.JadeScope);
content = window.compile(content)(processedWidget.JadeScope);

//Angular Black Magic:
if(processedWidget.JadeScope.$apply)
    processedWidget.JadeScope.$apply();

SDB.AddWidget(processedWidget);
processedWidget.SetContent(content);
```

Note the $apply call and the addition of window.compile, which is simply a reference to the $compile function injected in the Angular CTOR.